# SQL Count goes crazy when joined

Tags: sql, oracle, count

So i have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT   COUNT("Oprettet af Initialer") AS meetings_booked
FROM     KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR
WHERE    "Oprettet dato" = '2013-08-12'
AND      "Oprettet af Initialer" = 'JOEB'
```

Now this returns the right number (71)

Now this was just a test i have to do the same for the whole table but only include some where `Oprettet af Initialer` is equal to the row `Initialer` in another table.

For this i decided to use a join:

```
SELECT   COUNT("Oprettet af Initialer") AS meetings_booked
FROM     KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR INNER JOIN KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO ON KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR."Oprettet af Initialer" = KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO.INITIALER
WHERE    "Oprettet dato" = '2013-08-12'
AND      "Oprettet af Initialer" = 'JOEB'
```

How ever when i run this i get the following output:181476.

Which is clearly a mistake!

Now i have a gut feeling telling me that it is counting everything from both rows however i have no idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there are several rows in V_TEAM_DATO matching KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR,
try this instead:

```
SELECT   COUNT("Oprettet af Initialer") AS meetings_booked
FROM     KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR 
WHERE exists
(SELECT 1 FROM KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO 
WHERE KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR."Oprettet af Initialer" = KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO.INITIALER
)
AND "Oprettet dato" = '2013-08-12'
AND "Oprettet af Initialer" = 'JOEB'
```

Comment: Worked!§ thank you will this work even though i dont have the AND "Oprettet af Initialer" = 'JOEB' ?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Yes, you can put any condition you want on columns in `meetings_booked` after the exists clause's end parenthesis.